# How do credit card companies get funds to lend for consumers

Tags: credit-card

Credit card companies need funds to pay to the service providers on behalf of the end consumers and consumers pay back later. So credit card company is lending money to the consumers.

Where do they get fundings? Do they borrow money from banks or issues company bonds to raise money?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit card companies *are* banks, generally. Visa is a platform, a network, a technology company. But the 'issuer', meaning the lender, is usually a bank such as Chase.

https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/everything-you-need-to-know-about-credit-card-issuers/